# Validating NaN value in an XML input against an XSD which restrict the NaN value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to validate double NaN value against an XSD schema which suppose to prevent such a NaN value. However it seems valid in .NET.

I also tested this with other XML validators such as online tools and Altova XML Spy. These tools do not accept NaN value!

I am using the following XSD schema

```
<xs:element name="myDouble">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
          <xs:minExclusive value="-INF"/>
          <xs:maxExclusive value="INF"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

It seems valid when I am trying to validate the input with .NET XML libraries:

```
<myDouble>NaN</myDouble>
```

However, I realized that the online XML validators and tools like Altova XML Spy says that this input is invalid.

I couldnt understand why there is such a different behaviour?

Whole code can be found in the following github repo:
https://github.com/ozgurtuzgen/DoubleNaNValidation

Comment: The Microsoft schema validator has much worse non-conformances than this; its regular expression handling, for example, follows .NET conventions rather than following the W3C specifications.